# DataTable como hacer que reconozca el campo fecha como tal?

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatable

Estoy trabajando con DataTable y defini una funcion Tabla Paginada en js

para ordenar por fecha , inserte en el html un th y td oculto . funciono.
Pero el defecto es que cuando se apreta el boton para ordenar asc o desc desde la tabla , datatable no lee el formato fecha , interpreta como string

```
function TablaPaginada(nombreTabla,colOrdenar,fOrdenar){
var tabla = '#'+nombreTabla;
var columnaOrdenar = colOrdenar;
var formaOrdenar = fOrdenar;
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(tabla).DataTable( {
            "lengthMenu": [[5, 10, 15, 25, 50], [5, 10, 15, 25, 50]],
            "language": {
                "sProcessing":     "Procesando...",
                "sLengthMenu":     "Mostrar&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp _MENU_ &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;registros",
                "sZeroRecords":    "No se encontraron resultados",
                "sEmptyTable":     "Ningún dato disponible en esta tabla",
                "sInfo":           "Del _START_ al _END_ de un total de _TOTAL_ reg.",
                "sInfoEmpty":      "0 registros",
                "sInfoFiltered":   "(filtrado de _MAX_ reg.)",
                "sInfoPostFix":    "",
                "sSearch":         "Buscar:&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp",
                "sUrl":            "",
                "sInfoThousands":  ",",
                "sLoadingRecords": "Cargando...",
                "oPaginate": {
                    "sFirst":    "Primero",
                    "sLast":     "Último",
                    "sNext":     "Sig",
                    "sPrevious": "Ant"
                },
                "oAria": {
                    "sSortAscending":  ": Activar para ordenar la columna de manera ascendente",
                    "sSortDescending": ": Activar para ordenar la columna de manera descendente"
                }
            },
            "aaSorting": [[columnaOrdenar,formaOrdenar]]
    }
    );
} );
```

}

como puedo pasarle un parametro para decirle que la columna ejemplo 2 es un formato date?

Comment: Prueba con esto de los [datos ortogonales](https://datatables.net/manual/data/orthogonal-data)  de datatables

Answer (score 0):

encontramos muchas maneras complicadas de resolverlo, pero la mas fácil

que pensamos resulto esta:

```
   <p style="visibility: hidden"> <?php echo $item['fecha']?>   </p>
```

dejamos que datatable lo ordene como sabe, pero lo ocultamos. Y mostramos la que queremos que se vea.